# Rotating and translating a 2D image with OpenGL fixed function

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

My code draws a texture on a 2D quad which should be translated, rotated and scaled:

```
double width = ... //window width
double height = ... //window height
double imagewidth = ... 
double imageheight = ...
vec2 usertranslation = ... //additional translation in x,y direction from user input
double rot_angle = ... //rotation angle from user input

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, width, 0.0, height, 0.0, -1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// translate to the top center of the image and add user input translation
double transx = (width - imagewidth) / 2 + usertranslation.x;
double transy = height - imageheight + usertranslation.y;
glTranslatef(transx, transy, 0);

//this currently rotates around the center of the image, but what I need
//is to rotate the image around the center of the window. 
glTranslatef(imagewidth / 2, imageheight / 2, 0);
glRotatef(rot_angle, 0, 0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(-imagewidth / 2, -imageheight / 2, 0);

//bind the texture and draw the quad
drawTexturedQuad();
```

Now my question is, what do I need to change to let the image always rotate around the center point of the window. I already tried somehting like this for the rotation:

```
glTranslatef(imagewidth / 2, imageheight - usertranslation.y - height, 0);
glRotatef(rot_angle, 0, 0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(-imagewidth  / 2, -(imageheight - usertranslation.y - height), 0);
```

But then I get a inverted top down translation if the image was rotated for 180 degrees (the image moves in the oposite direction on translation).

Answer (score 0):

To rotate around the center of the screen (0,0) you can change your entity's position according these equations:

x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
y = x * sin(angle) - y * cos(angle)

Where x and y are the positions of your entity and angle is the angle of rotation. If you want to face the same point after rotation, like the center of the rotation, you also have to rotate your entity around its center by negative angle. This is the same what a rotation matrix use, but

If you want to rotate around a specific point you have to use coordinates relative to that point. Thats easy just substract the center point coordinates of the coordinates of your entity, do the rotation and add your center coordinates to your new position.
This is important because you were relative to an other point not the center and this is how vectors work.